# Trouble understanding functions

Tags: c++, function, multidimensional-array

Basically I have a treasure map and the user is trying to find the treasure. The treasure map is supposed to be printed with a 2D array. We are supposed to call functions for randomizing the treasure and start location, for each turn the user has, etc.

I don't know how to declare my variables in my functions. I am having to redeclare each time I write a function, but my professor says I should only declare once?

Main function written by my professor:

```
int main() 
{
   char Map[ROWS][COLS];
   int TreasureR, TreasureC; 
   int StartR, StartC; 
   int Row, Col;   
   int NumMoves = 0;          // The number of player moves
   bool Winner = false;
   bool Quit = false;

   cout << "This homework was written by Savanna Bruce.\n";
   cout << "You are stranded on a desert island with no idea how to survive.\n";
   cout << "Fortunately, there are tools to survive and a hidden Treasure!\n";
   cout << "Find the Treasure!!!\n\n\n";


   // Seed the random number variable
   srand (time(NULL));

   // Start a New Game or Continue an Old one
   InitMap (Map);

   // Add code to place the treasure and start
   Random();
   // Add code to play the game
   PlayTurn();
   // Print the Map, hide the Treasure
   PrintMap(Map, false);

   return 0;
}
```

My functions that I have so far:

```
// Name: InitMap
// Description: Initialize the Map with all EMPTY cells
// Return: Nothing
// ---------------------------------------------------
void InitMap(char Map[][COLS])
{
    Map = 0;
}
// ---------------------------------------------------
void Random()
{
    int TreasureC, TreasureR;
    int StartC, StartR;
    int Col, Row;

    // Set the location of the treasure chest
    TreasureC = rand() % COLS;   // set to a value in range 0..XDIM-1
    TreasureR = rand() % ROWS;   // set to a value in range 0..YDIM-1

    // Set the starting location of the player
    StartC = rand() % COLS;      // set to a value in range 0..XDIM-1
    StartR = rand() % ROWS;      // set to a value in range 0..YDIM-1
    Col = StartC;
    Row = StartR;
}

void PrintMap(const char Map[][COLS], const bool showTreasure) 
{
    int TreasureR = 0;
    int TreasureC = 0;

    for (int row = 0; row < ROWS; row++)
    {
       for (int col = 0; col < COLS; col++)
       {
           if ((row == TreasureR && col == TreasureC) && showTreasure == true)
               cout << TREASURE;
           else
               cout << EMPTY;
       }
    cout <<  endl;
    }

}
```

Global variables:

```
const int FAST = 3;
const int SLOW = 5;
const int COLS = 20;                // For MAP Size
const int ROWS = 10;                // For MAP Size
const int MAX_ROW = ROWS - 1;       // valid locations are 0..ROWS - 1
const int MAX_COL = COLS - 1;       // valid locations are 0..COLS - 1
const string FILENAME = "Map.txt";  // File to save/load Map from

// Cell types - The Map can have any of these
// characters at a location on a Map.
const char START = 'S';
const char PLAYER = 'P';
const char TREASURE = 'T';
const char EMPTY = '*';
const char VISITED = 'X';
```

Can someone please tell me if any of these are right and whether I should have to be declaring my variables over and over again?

Comment: If your professor wrote `main` then I don't understand his/her intent. It looks like `TreasureC` and `TreasureR` are meant to either be global variables or class members, but your professor declared them in `main` as local variables, which makes no sense. I would go back to the professor and ask for clarification.

Comment: Just posted the global variables given

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you're redeclaring

```
int TreasureR, TreasureC; 
int StartR, StartC; 
int Row, Col;
```

in both `main` and in `Random`

Simply pass those values by reference to `Random()` to solve your issue:

```
void Random(int& TreasureC, int& TreasureR, int& StartC, int& startR, int& Col, int& Row)
{
    // Set the location of the treasure chest
    TreasureC = rand() % COLS;   // set to a value in range 0..XDIM-1
    TreasureR = rand() % ROWS;   // set to a value in range 0..YDIM-1

    // Set the starting location of the player
    StartC = rand() % COLS;      // set to a value in range 0..XDIM-1
    StartR = rand() % ROWS;      // set to a value in range 0..YDIM-1
    Col = StartC;
    Row = StartR;
}
```

Do the same with your `PrintMap` function.

You should look into tutorials on [understanding variable scope](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_variable_scope.htm). That is, when you declare a variable, it only "lives" for a certain amount of time (usually between `{}`). When you declare those variables inside of `main`, they don't magically also live in your functions. You should declare them once, and then pass them to the functions that need them.

Your `InitMap()` function should actually iterate over all cells in the matrix and set them to something. `Map = 0` doesn't do that. You need to loop over rows and columns like you do in `PrintMap`

Finally, in `Random()`, while you are indeed computing a row and column, you're not actually "putting" anything in Map. The way you're doing things, you don't actually need a `Map` data structure; you can just choose a treasure row and column, and then use your `PrintMap()` function as-is.

Comment: If the professor didn't dictate how the functions were to be declared then this answer is correct.

Comment: I guess I am having trouble understanding how to initialize an array and make it completely empty. I see how to do it if the array is filled with numbers, buy my array is a character array.

Comment: @savannaalexis: `Map[row][col] = '0'` Note that I said `'0'` instead of `0`, as `'0'` is a `char` and `0` is an `int`.

Comment: I really appreciate your help. I think I have it figured out now. Thank you.